# How to polish welding at 90 degree curves?

Tags: railing, welding

We have given contract to the local railings constructor and they have put the railing Balusters on the floor along with clips to put glass on. I am satisfied with their work so far, only thing that is bugging me is the weird looking welding work near the clips.

This is how they look after polishing

[image]

[image]

He says his grinding wheel does not reach the corners, so he cannot smooth it out.

Is there anyway to fix this issue ?

Comment: is that weld just a blob? ... the picture is not very clear ... it looks like there is a gap just above the weld ... if there is a gap, then it will collect crud

Comment: yes its just a blob, ... I am not sure if that is the right way of doing things.

Comment: @jsotola yes there is a gap at the top, should I ask him to weld that area also ?

Comment: Even as a non-welder, I can tell that's bad. It should be a smooth bead going all the way down, not just a random dollop.

Comment: Stainless can be a pita it may be strong but should be pickled and buffed so it doesn’t look dissimilar , a polish can be tough on brushed surfaces I can’t tell for sure but jewelers rouge on a cloth disk may bring up a shine

Comment: Railings = safety equipment = it has to be (re)done correctly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That welding would be termed by one of my instructors as “bird droppings”...

It needs to be done properly where the weld joins and fills the 90 gap evenly and is called a fillet weld.

Get them to grind it out and do it properly. A 4” angle grinder with a new disc will get into that.

Have a look at some of the welds shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrS_yafue6M

Comment: “bird droppings” so basically this question is "how do i polish a turd?"

Answer (score 10):

A rule of thumb is that a good weld looks good . Your base metals look like stainless ; If it is strongly magnetic it is ferritic or martensitic. If one of those the welder must use the right fillers to avoid hard brittle welds. The weld shown does not inspire confidence.

Comment: I agree the base filler needs to be correct but the question is how to polish.

Comment: That was the question  but I don't think polishing will help. I think it is grind and re-weld.

Comment: Its 304 stainless steel

Comment: Good, 304 ( non-magnetic ) is no problem